# Initialize array of HKEY correctly

Tags: windows, registry, handle

How to effectively initialize array of `HKEY`?

Consider the following code snippet

```
HKEY hkey[2];

for(int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)

LONG reval = RegOpenKeyEx(/* parameters */,&hkey[i]);
```

`RegOpenKeyEx()` will fill the array based on the parameters that i pass. But what is the best way to initialize the HKEY array? I could not find any msdn documentation regarding the same.

Is it good enough to do `HKEY hkey[2] = {0 };` ????

Comment: Just {} is good enough to get NULLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to initialise the array. You can let `RegOpenKeyEx` set the values. You do not need to assign them to anything before calling `RegOpenKeyEx`. The documentation states that the `HKEY` parameter has out semantics and so its value on input is not used.

You must perform error checking though, to make sure that you detect that the function has failed and so do not use uninitialized values.

It won't hurt to do

```
HKEY hkey[2] = { NULL, NULL };
```

before you call `RegOpenKeyEx`. But so long as you perform proper error checking on the call to `RegOpenKeyEx` there's no way that function can complete successfully and not assign to the `HKEY` parameter.